# RMS service is disabled for publishing for this user

Tags: microsoft-information-protection

When trying to apply a label using file api Suddenly started getting this error "Something bad happened: RMS service is disabled for publishing for this user.,ServiceDisabledError.Extent=User"

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Hi.. Have you got any solution for this error? If so, could you please share..